# How to calculate Bone Length in 3Ds Max

Tags: 3dsmax, maxscript

I am creating a script to help me speed up my rigging workflow. I am trying to create an automatic size adjustment for helpers that I am assigning to bones. That way longer bones will have larger helpers and smaller bones smaler helpers.

I decided to do this by calculating length of the bone as you can see below.

```
xyz1 = point3 $.pos.x $.pos.y $.pos.z --takes position from first bone
actionMan.executeAction 0 "40194" --moves to the next bone in chain
xyz2 = point3 $.pos.x $.pos.y $.pos.z --takes position from second bone

intensity = distance xyz2 xyz1 --calculate vector length

actionMan.executeAction 0 "40193" --moves to the previous bone in chain
loc = point()
loc.size = intensity*0.5 --defines the size of the helper
loc.position = $.position
```

Is there any easier way to do this? Because I have to use this in a "for" loop, when I select multiple bones, using actionMan to select other elements is not possible since it creates problems with selection.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apart from the `length` property of the bones (is there any reason not to use that?), you can get the first child which is a bone and get its distance. That is, if you have the top parent bone of the chain selected:

```
for b in #()+$ where isKindOf b BoneObj collect b.length
```

This will include also the last bone. Or by testing the parent-child distance:

```
for b in #()+$ where isKindOf b BoneObj and b.children.count > 0 collect distance b b.children[1]
```

Comment: Could you write me a piece of code for reference (for both cases)?
Thank you

Comment: Thank you so much! You have been a great help.